# How to publish Python dependencies to artifactory pypi with ivy & gradle

Tags: python, gradle, ivy, pypi

I saw that we can publish repositories to pypi with ivy and gradle.
I saw that the settings.gradle or in your build.gradle there should be something like this:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        ivy {
            url '<pypi-artifactory-url>'
            layout 'pattern', {
                artifact '[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-revision.[ext]'
                ivy '[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision].ivy'
                m2compatible = true
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I also saw this plugin: http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/Gradle_User_Guide.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/userguide/publishing_ivy.html

But I have a hard time understanding how to adapt it to publish to pypi